# XML writing multiple Attributes

Tags: xml, xmlwriter

Hell everyone, im trying to rewrite current XML file into a new XML file without the items which are no more listed for sale but unfortunetly I seem to miss something out

this is the Orginal XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<imgdir name="Commodity.img">
    <imgdir name="0">
        <int name="SN" value="10000000"/>
        <int name="ItemId" value="1002000"/>
        <int name="Count" value="1"/>
        <int name="Price" value="300"/>
        <int name="Period" value="14"/>
        <int name="Priority" value="8"/>
        <int name="Gender" value="2"/>
        <int name="OnSale" value="0"/>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="1">
        <int name="SN" value="10000001"/>
        <int name="ItemId" value="1002015"/>
        <int name="Count" value="1"/>
        <int name="Price" value="300"/>
        <int name="Period" value="14"/>
        <int name="Priority" value="8"/>
        <int name="Gender" value="2"/>
        <int name="OnSale" value="0"/>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="2">
        <int name="SN" value="10000002"/>
        <int name="ItemId" value="1002187"/>
        <int name="Count" value="1"/>
        <int name="Price" value="300"/>
        <int name="Period" value="14"/>
        <int name="Priority" value="8"/>
        <int name="Gender" value="2"/>
        <int name="OnSale" value="0"/>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="3">
        <int name="SN" value="10000003"/>
        <int name="ItemId" value="1002292"/>
        <int name="Count" value="1"/>
        <int name="Price" value="300"/>
        <int name="Period" value="14"/>
        <int name="Priority" value="8"/>
        <int name="Gender" value="2"/>
        <int name="OnSale" value="0"/>
    </imgdir>
```

and this is the output I get from my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><imgdir xmlns="Commodity.img">
<imgdir SN="10002304" ItemId="5010073" Count="1" Price="3300" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="2" />
<imgdir SN="10002305" ItemId="5010074" Count="1" Price="3300" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="3" />
<imgdir SN="10002306" ItemId="1022104" Count="1" Price="3300" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="4" />
<imgdir SN="10002307" ItemId="9102232" Count="1" Price="16900" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="5" />
<imgdir SN="10002308" ItemId="1003050" Count="1" Price="2500" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="6" />
<imgdir SN="10002309" ItemId="1022102" Count="1" Price="3200" Period="90" Priority="12" Gender="2" OnSale="1" xmlns="7" />
</imgdir>
```

any suggestions what im doing wrong?

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("NewXml.xml");
            int number = 0;
            string OLD_itemSN = "0";
            writer.WriteStartElement("imgdir", "Commodity.img");
            foreach (Cashitem item in Cashitems)
            {

                if (item.OnSale != 0)
                {
                    if (item.SN.ToString() != OLD_itemSN)
                    {
                        number++;
                        OLD_itemSN = item.SN.ToString();
                    }
                    writer.WriteStartElement("imgdir", number.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("SN", item.SN.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("ItemId", item.ItemId.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Count", item.Count.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Price", item.Price.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Period", item.Period.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Priority", item.Priority.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Gender", item.Gender.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("OnSale", item.OnSale.ToString());
                    if (item.Limit != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Limit", item.Limit);
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();


        }
```

in my output I miss imgdir Name= Value
and int before every attribute
im really desperated :(

Comment: Is it C# language?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse *attribute* and *element*!

Try this code:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("NewXml.xml", settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument(standalone: true);

    int number = 0;
    string OLD_itemSN = "0";
    writer.WriteStartElement("imgdir");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "Commodity.img");

    foreach (Cashitem item in Cashitems)
    {
        if (item.OnSale != 0)
        {
            if (item.SN.ToString() != OLD_itemSN)
            {
                number++;
                OLD_itemSN = item.SN.ToString();
            }
            writer.WriteStartElement("imgdir");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("name", number.ToString());

            WriteIntNode(writer, "SN", item.SN.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "ItemId", item.ItemId.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "Count", item.Count.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "Price", item.Price.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "Period", item.Period.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "Priority", item.Priority.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "Gender", item.Gender.ToString());
            WriteIntNode(writer, "OnSale", item.OnSale.ToString());

            if (item.Limit != null)
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Limit", item.Limit);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

An additional method:

```
void WriteIntNode(XmlWriter writer, string name, string value)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("int");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", name);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("value", value);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```